# Is optimal substructure always means overlapping problems?

Tags: dynamic-programming

So I'm currently studying about "Dynamic programming", one thing I'm wondering is that "Is optimal substructure always means overlapping problems?" Can you guys show me an optimization problem that don't have overlapping problems but still have optimal substructure?